# CLIPS expert system and Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clips

Summary:
I am creating a pre-hospital medical simulation package (for Emergency Medical Technicians) and need help setting up CLIPS in Unity via C# scripts.

Long Story:
I began this project years ago and successfully prototyped it with CLIPS, Visual Basic, Flash, and Microsoft animating Agent characters. I am now in the process of porting my project over to Unity (a 3D game engine) and am trying to use the Unity C# tool for calling CLIPS. I am struggling a little with the proper set-up and context. I researched a code sample of how to call CLIPS from C#, but the syntax is slightly different in Unity C# (for example, there is no "Main" class)

Can anyone help me? I have been researching this with the Unity programmers for months and have gotten nowhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should provide what you have so far.  People will not do the work from scratch for you

Comment: The closest I found in my research was the following sample: using System;

namespace GetMarriedOrStaySingle_AsCSharpApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CLIPSNet.Environment theEnv = new CLIPSNet.Environment();
            theEnv.Load(@"..\..\..\SocratesKnowledgeBase.clp");
            theEnv.Reset();
            theEnv.Run(-1);
        }
    }
}